# My query is really slow even though it has an index

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

We have to check 7 million rows to make campagne statistics. It takes around 30 seconds to run the query and it doesnt improve with indexes.

Indexes didnt change the speed at all.

I tried adding indexes on the where fields, the where fields + group by and the where fields + sum.

Server type is MYSQL and the server version is 5.5.31.

```
SELECT
    NOW(), `banner_campagne`.name, `banner_view`.banner_uid, SUM(`banner_view`.fetched) AS fetched,
    SUM(`banner_view`.loaded) AS loaded,
    SUM(`banner_view`.seen) AS seen
FROM `banner_view` INNER JOIN
     `banner_campagne`
     ON `banner_campagne`.uid = `banner_view`.banner_uid AND
        `banner_campagne`.deleted = 0 AND 
        `banner_campagne`.weergeven = 1
WHERE
    `banner_view`.campagne_uid = 6 AND `banner_view`.datetime >= '2019-07-31 00:00:00' AND `banner_view`.datetime < '2019-08-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    `banner_view`.banner_uid
```

I expect the query to run around 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The indexes that you want for this query are probably:

- `banner_view(campagne_uid, datetime)`
- `banner_campagne(banner_uid, weergeven, deleted)`

Note that the order of the columns in the index does matter.